# Grails: field access with GORM

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Hibernate uses method calls to get the values of domain class properties by default. How can I configure direct field access with GORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not directly supported but will be in 1.4. For now you can enable it with a custom Configuration subclass as described at http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GORM-setting-access-quot-field-quot-td1592837.html#a1594428

I did a small post about subclassing Configuration with links to specific examples at http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=465

Comment: It took me a while to get that working because I didn't understand that all I had to do was dump in your code and it would change the behavior for every field except id.  Thanks for making it too easy as usual Burt!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this is due to how groovy implements [Beans convention](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans) therefore not something that can be configured for GORM.